# Who are Bogdan and Björn in "Bogdan/Björn's Erlang Abstract Machine"? (BEAM)

Tags: erlang

I understand that the acronym for Erlang's virtual machine, BEAM, stands for "Bogdan/Björn's Erlang Abstract Machine".

But I can't find definitive reference anywhere to exactly who Bogdan and Björn are.

Searching the erlang.org mailing list I do see posts by developers named "Bogdan Andu" and "Björn-Egil Dahlberg". Can anyone confirm, are these the engineers that BEAM is named after?

Comment: Interesting, but not really on-topic.

Comment: AFAIK Björn = [Björn Gustavsson](http://www.erlang.se/~bjorn/) and Bogdan = [Bogumil Hausman](http://www.cs-lab.org/historical_beam_instruction_set.html). There's a [reference](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/1999-June/000368.html) indicating the latter on the erlang-questions mailing list. Both were employees at Ericsson at some time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming at all.

Comment: Bogumil "Bogdan" Hausman and Björn Gustavsson are correct.

Comment: Favorited this question. I think it can belong here.  You should know the history behind the software you use.

Answer (score 13):

[Erlang and OTP in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/erlang-and-otp-in-action) on page 17 says that BEAM means Bogdan's Erlang Abstract Machine. Also see this [errata](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596518189) - scroll down to page 41. Here is the [history of the Erlang VM](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/247/erlang_vm_1.pdf) - BEAM was not the first and only VM capable of executing Erlang code! Bogdan is actually an [English version of Bogumil](http://www.erlang.se/publications/jubileumsskrift.html). All those names are employees at Ericsson who worked on implementing the language and its execution environment after Joe Armstrong's initial implementation in Prolog.